# Visualize points in Rviz2

Tags: ros, robotics, ros2, rviz

I have x,y and z coordinates. How can I visualize them as vectors in rviz so that their center is the origin.

I want to see magnitude and direction of the vectors in rviz2.x,y and z are contınuesly changing so vector which i want to create should be this.How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you'll have to publish [markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker).
The processe is basically the same as in ROS1. As most of the things in ROS2.

Here's an example: http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/rviz(2f)Tutorials(2f)Markers(3a20)Basic(20)Shapes.html

You can use something like this:

```
#include <chrono>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

#include <visualization_msgs/msg/marker.hpp>

class pub_view : public rclcpp::Node
{

    visualization_msgs::msg::Marker marker;
    rclcpp::Publisher<visualization_msgs::msg::Marker>::SharedPtr marker_pub;

    public:
    pub_view()
    : Node("pub_view"), count_(0)
    {
        marker_pub = this->create_publisher<visualization_msgs::msg::Marker>("Origin",10);

        marker.header.frame_id = "map";
        marker.header.stamp = this->get_clock().get()->now();
        marker.id = 0;
        marker.type = visualization_msgs::msg::Marker::SPHERE;
        marker.action = visualization_msgs::msg::Marker::ADD;
        marker.pose.position.x = 0; marker.pose.position.y = 0; marker.pose.position.z = 0;
        marker.pose.orientation.x = 0; marker.pose.orientation.y = 0; marker.pose.orientation.z = 0; marker.pose.orientation.w = 0;
        marker.scale.x = 2.5; marker.scale.y = 2.5; marker.scale.z = 2.5;
        marker.color.r = 1.0; marker.color.g = 0.0; marker.color.b = 0.0; marker.color.a = 0.5;
    }

    pub_sphere(){
        // Update timestamp
        marker.action = visualization_msgs::msg::Marker::MODIFY;
        marker.header.stamp = this->get_clock().get()->now();

        // Update pose
        marker.pose.position.x = 0; marker.pose.position.y = 0; marker.pose.position.z = 0;
        marker.pose.orientation.x = 0; marker.pose.orientation.y = 0; marker.pose.orientation.z = 0; marker.pose.orientation.w = 0;

        marker_pub->publish(marker);
    }
}
```

This code publishes a sphere marker. I did not tested the code but it should be something similar to this. Make sure that you're using the correct 'frame_id' or you'll not be able to visualize the markers on rviz.